# Can ViewModel in asp.net mvc-5 be used for login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In my asp.net project I'm using a ViewModel called DoctorLoginViewModel.cs which is used for rendering the Login view.
I was wondering if this ViewModel can be used in login ActionMethod

Credentials are in doc_cred table

DoctorLoginViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace das.Models.ViewModel.Doctor
{
    [Table("doc_cred")]
    public class DoctorLoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string doc_email { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string doc_pass { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string confirm_doc_pass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I have under doc_cred.cs:

```
namespace das.Models.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class doc_cred
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public doc_cred()
        {
            this.doc_personal = new HashSet<doc_personal>();
        }
    
        public string doc_email { get; set; }
        public string doc_pass { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime doc_acc_creation { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<doc_personal> doc_personal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have in my DoctorController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(doc_cred dl)
{
   var login = db.doc_cred.Where(a => a.doc_email.Equals(dl.doc_email) && 
   a.doc_pass.Equals(dl.doc_pass)).FirstOrDefault();
   if(login != null)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Doctor");
   }
   return View();
}
```

Now my question is can I use my ViewModel for login?
If so how?

EDIT: Here's my Login.cshtml:

```
    @model das.Models.ViewModel.Doctor.DoctorLoginViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    }
    
    <h2>Login</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DoctorLoginViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.doc_email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.doc_email, new { htmlAttributes 
  = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.doc_email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.doc_pass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.doc_pass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.doc_pass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirm_doc_pass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.confirm_doc_pass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirm_doc_pass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(DoctorLoginViewModel dl)
{
   var login = db.doc_cred.Where(a => a.doc_email.Equals(dl.doc_email) && 
   a.doc_pass.Equals(dl.doc_pass)).FirstOrDefault();
   if(login != null)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Doctor");
   }
   return View();
}
```

Please try this.

Comment: Login View is as before but I can't log in.
Do I have to map the doc_cred.cs from ViewModel somehow?

Comment: Remove the => [Table("doc_cred")] from the DoctorLoginViewModel and give it a try. It should work because view model does not need to have table attribute.

Comment: it worked thanks. I do not Understand though....i thought [Table("doc_cred")] was needed to map the doc_cred table from viewmodel